# Clicking button in mapped cards open hidden card for all other mapped cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an MUI card which is dynamically mapped depending on the JSON response from an API.  Each card has a comment.  Clicking on the comment opens another hidden card which displays the complete comment.  Because of how I am using state, each time I click on a comment, the hidden card will open for all mapped cards, instead of just the one I clicked.  How can I change this to just open the one hidden card?

```
const [showContextCard, setShowContextCard] = useState(false);
...
<Box className={classes.groupCards}>
    {questionGroups?.displaygroups?.ConslutingQuestions &&
    questionGroups?.displaygroups?.ConslutingQuestions?.map((group, groupIndex) => {
        function handleShowContext() {
            if (!showContextCard) {
                    setShowContextCard(true);
            } else setShowContextCard(false);
        }
        return (
            <>
                <Card className={classes.card}>
                    <CardHeader className={classes.cardTitle} title={group.GroupName} subheader={group.OwnerName} />
                </Card>
                <Card hidden={!showContextCard} className={classes.contextCard}>Comment Card</Card>
            </>
        );
    })}
</Box>
```